# Python: math.acos(x) for list

Tags: python, function, trigonometry

Here is my function to apply Inverse cosinus on my list

```
import math

ListAcos = lambda x: math.acos(float(x))

ListAcos(Mylist)

cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

My list is a series like to following one

```
ID
25      -0.239509
26      -0.274846
27      -0.316483
28      -0.330328
29      -0.266320

37371    0.628767
37372    0.687516
37373    0.700680
37374    0.731391
37375    0.693018
Length: 36223, dtype: float64
```

Anyone know the transformation I should apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is not numpy.

The standard library function `math.acos` only operates on a floating point scalar (ie a single value). You need `np.arccos` to operate on a numpy array:

```
np.arccos(MyList.values)
```

Or if you want the resul to be a Series:

```
np.arccos(MyList)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use `pandas.Series.apply` method to make your transformation, as you can insert your lambda function within the mehtod:

```
MyList = MyList.apply(ListAcos)
```